# how to use ChangeNotifierProvider.value properly to pass state from screen 1 to 2

Tags: flutter, state, provider

I have 2 screens homepage and detailpage. I want to rebuild widget inside detailpage based on a certain action but the issue is the data come from homepage through http request and a specific object is passed to the second screen in purpose to display detail on it.

```
     class ListPage extends StatefulWidget {
       @override
       _ListPageState createState() => _ListPageState();
        }

     class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {
            ParcelModel model = ParcelModel();
          
          @override
          void initState() {
             model.loadData();
             super.initState();
           }

        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
            return MultiProvider(
                 providers: [
                        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ParcelModel()),
                   ],
           child: DefaultTabController(
                 length: 3,
          child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => model,
             child: Consumer<ParcelModel>(
             builder:(context, model, child){
            if(model.failed == true){
              return Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                body:TabBarView(children:[
                  mescolis(context.watch<ParcelModel().listParcel),futureWidget_quotation(),
                  Payezcolisencoursdelivraison(context.watch<ParcelModel>().listParcel),
                ]),
                floatingActionButton:FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                           MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder:(context) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                                    value:model,
         child:Formtest(dataPays:context.watch<ParcelModel().listParcel,newsecontext:context,) //trying to pass the model here
                                )
                            );
                         }
                         )
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

Now I am trying to pass the model to the second screen inside a button but it does'nt work this is the function from the detail page when I press this it does not rebuild the homepage (screen 1)

```
         new RaisedButton(  
          onPressed: (){
             try{
            Provider.of<ParcelModel>(newContext,listen: false).postData(
                formData,
                dio,
                context,
                nom_coli_Controller,
                description_coli_Controller,
                nature_Controller,
                nom_coli_Controller
            );
          }catch(e){
            FlutterFlexibleToast.showToast(
              message: "error",
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
              timeInSeconds:30,
              radius: 70,
            );
          }
               },  
          child: new Text("Press here"),),
```